# Is there a difference between %1 and %1% in windows batch scripts?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I amtrying to understand the difference between `%1` and `%1%` in batch scripts, but either the explanations given in SO do not make sense, are wrong, or I have a complete misunderstanding or the test script is working incorrectly.

On Windows 7 I am using the script given [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/6b7d6b97-3b08-4b14-8b7e-77840fb02c2f/difference-between-1-and-1-in-batch-scripting?forum=ITCG):

```
@echo off
set Name=Amit
set 1=First
set 2=Second
echo My own environmental variables are:
echo Name=%Name%, 1=%1%, 2=%2%"
echo The user invoked this batch file with a parameter of %1
```

which give the following output:

```
> tester.bat
My own environmental variables are:
Name=Amit, 1=2"
The user invoked this batch file with a parameter of .
```

and

```
> tester.bat test
My own environmental variables are:
Name=Amit, 1=test2"
```

My conclusion: `%1` and `%1%` are equivalent. Is this so?
    The user invoked this batch file with a parameter of test.

.

---

As suggested by foxidrive:

```
@echo off
echo %1% abc %2%
pause
echo %1 abc %2
pause
```

Run as `tester.bat aaa bbb` gives first output: `aaa2` and second output `aaa abc bbb`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `%1%` is incorrect syntax.

Launch this batch file like so to see how it can affect a script: **file.bat aaa bbb**

```
@echo off
echo %1% abc %2%
pause
echo %1 abc %2
pause
```

Here is the console output for the above:

```
aaa2
Press any key to continue . . .
aaa abc bbb
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This happens because the term `%1% abc %2%` is parsed as `%1`
and then an environment variable called `% abc %` which is not defined in the above scenario,
plus a `2` and a lone `%` which is discarded.

Comment: What is the result of this script?

Comment: aaa2
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
aaa abc bbb
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .

Comment: @Pascal: I only have a German installation of Windows. I wish I had it in englich. Output of script for Pascal: The forst echo prints `aaa2`, the second echo prints `aaa abc bbb`.

Comment: @Alex thank you (I think the output of the script should be part of the answer, as people reading it may not have any Windows installation available and still be curious about it)

Comment: Your edit was already in my idea at first. Your point was that `%1%` is an incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.

First thing you need to no know is that the `%1` and `%2`  will be expanded first so here:

`echo Name=%Name%, 1=%1%, 2=%2%"`

you are echoing following variables `%name%`  ,  `%1`  , `%, 2=%`  (and variable `, 2=` is not defined (it's even not possible to declare a variable with `=` in its name)) and at the end there is one left `%`

the `echo %` (alone) will have different behavior in command prompt and in a batch - in command prompt it will print the `%` but in batch will try to expand it but as it is not enclosed it will be interpreted as ..hmm nothing and will print `ECHO is off.` or `ECHO is on.` So every single `%` at the end will be ignored

The second thing - the only way that pops up in mind at the moment for accessing `%1%` variable is with delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set 1=one
echo !1!
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

`%1` will always be parsed as `%1` and the `%` that could follow it does not give any effect on it. `%` is just ignored or perhaps silently expands to nothing when no parameter identity is placed in front of it.

```
echo a% b
```

is just the same as saying

```
echo a b
```

That would apply on scripts.